# Robotframework: The use of Wait Until Keyword Succeeds

Tags: python, robotframework, keyword

Am a noob at Robot, i would like to use the Wait Until Keyword Succeeds with my keywords but its always passed even when it should not. So i am trying to figure out what is the value of the return of my keyword that controls passed/failed.
As an example:
My keyword

```
def check_num(num):
    if num == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Am calling:
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds      5 times      2 s       check num       0
```

Am expecting it to run 5 times with 2sec pauses and fail at the end, but its always green. If its not True/False that should be used, can you please tell me what is expected?
Thank you.

Comment: I found a solution, which is to put an exception rather than False:
`else:
        raise ConfigException("KO")`

Comment: That's right, there's the reason (you might even add it as a self-answer). `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` basically waits until a keyword stops failing; and in your sample, it always passes - it has a `False` as a return value, but that's not an exceotion (failure, in RF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `False` isn’t considered a failure. A keyword only fails if it throws an exception.

```
def check_num(num):
    if num != 1:
        raise Exception(f”{num} is not 1”)
```

For more information see [Reporting keyword status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#reporting-keyword-status) in the robot framework user guide.